# using npm angular2-google-chart, how to i draw multiple charts on window.resize?

Tags: javascript, angular, google-visualization

I have two charts that I load on the same page/component. I am able to get them to display just fine when the page loads. My site is responsive and I need to redraw the charts on window.resize. Everything works fine when there is only one chart, but when I add a second chart to the page only the second(last) chart resizes on window.resize. How do I fix this?

I am using angular2 rc1, with angular2-google-chart: "https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-google-chart" 
on github: "https://github.com/vimalavinisha/angular2-google-chart"

index.html page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script>  
   /* googleLoaded = false allows for more than one chart per page */
   var googleLoaded = false;
</script>
```

google-charts.directive.ts:

```
import {
    Directive, 
    ElementRef,
    Input,
    OnInit } from '@angular/core';

declare var google       : any;
declare var googleLoaded : any;

@Directive( {
    selector: '[GoogleChart]',
    properties: [
        'chartType',
        'chartOptions',
        'chartData'
    ]
} )
export class GoogleChart implements OnInit {
    public _element : any;
    @Input( 'chartType')     public chartType    : string;
    @Input( 'chartOptions' ) public chartOptions : Object;
    @Input( 'chartData' )    public chartData    : Object;

    constructor( public element: ElementRef ) {
        this._element = this.element.nativeElement;
        //This is where I resize the charts, but it only resizes the last on on the page????
        window.onresize = ( e ) => {
            //you need to get all charts on the page somehow
            this.drawGraph(
                this.chartOptions,
                this.chartType, 
                this.chartData, 
                this._element
            )   
        }
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        if( !googleLoaded ) {
            googleLoaded = true;
            google.charts.load( 'current', { 'packages':['corechart', 'gauge'] } );
        }
        setTimeout( 
            () => this.drawGraph(
                this.chartOptions,
                this.chartType, 
                this.chartData, 
                this._element
            ), 500 );
    }

    drawGraph ( chartOptions, chartType, chartData, ele ) {
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback( drawChart );
        function drawChart() {
            var wrapper;
            wrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper( {
                chartType   : chartType,
                dataTable   : chartData ,
                options     : chartOptions || {},
                containerId : ele.id
            } );
            wrapper.draw();
        }
    }
}
```

my component where the charts display:

```
<div id="bar_chart" class="google-chart"
    [chartData]="bar_ChartData" 
    [chartOptions] = "bar_ChartOptions" 
    chartType="BarChart" 
    GoogleChart
></div>
<div id="pie_chart" class="google-chart" 
    [chartData]="pie_ChartData" 
    [chartOptions] = "pie_ChartOptions" 
    chartType="PieChart" 
    GoogleChart
></div>
```

I was able to create a different directive for each chart and get it to work, but depending on the page I might have to use 4 or 5 different charts and it seems a bit much.

tl;dr: I use google charts with angular2 rc1, and i get multiple charts to display, but when I resize the page, only the last chart re-draws itself. How do I re-draw multiple charts on the same page?